# Xcode the image is way too large need to be the size of the png image used not massive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, uiimageview

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPin.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedPin.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowPin.png"],
                                 nil];

        image.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        image.animationDuration = 1.0;
        [image startAnimating];

        [image setFrame: CGRectMake(point.x-(image.bounds.size.width/2), point.y-            (image.bounds.size.width/2), image.bounds.size.width, image.bounds.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview: image];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.0    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
            [image setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [image removeFromSuperview];

        }];
```

the images are coming out way too big they need to be their original size 
basically creates the images animation where the user touches and it fades away after x seconds

Comment: There's not enough context here to discern the intended behavior.  If the `UIImageView` dimensions are too large, then the initialization or the `setFrame:` is causing them to be so.  Do you intend the image view to be the same dimensions as the superview?  Because that's how you initialize it.  Also look at the `contentMode` property on `UIImageView`...

Comment: sorry relatively new to obj c what is the superview... and I want the UIImageView is be the size of the image used

Comment: When you create the `UIImageView` your initialization is making it the size of `self.view`.  If you want to make it exactly the size of one of the images it will ultimately contain then you need to grab one of the images and create the `UIImageView` based on its `size` property.

Comment: Oh, `superview` is the parent view in the view in the hierarchy to which you are adding your image view.

Comment: could you give me an example hehe sorry noob here

Answer (score 0):

You want the image view to be the same dimensions as the image it contains, right?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageName:@"BluePin.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height];
```

Note that I'm using a different variable naming scheme than yours to distinguish between an image and an image view.

Comment: but in mine the image isnt declared until after the view is

Comment: true. the intent is to first, determine the size of the target image so you can size the view accordingly.  The rest of your code e.g. `imageView.animationImages = ...` would follow.

Comment: UIImage *bPin = [[UIImage    alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"BluePin.png"];
            UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,bPin.size.width,bPin.size.height)];
            image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     bPin,